# iOS 9 Making Code go Sequentially (Touch ID)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am a developer using self-taught Objective-C to code for the iPhone. We are using Xcode 7 and iOS 9. I am tasked with creating an app for my company to communicate when someone arrives and leaves an appointment in a schedule made for them (using XML).

We would like to use Touch ID for security so the users don’t have to log in a lot. Security is required because of the confidentiality of the data in the app. I had the application working. Or it looked like it worked, until I clicked on the Cancel option in Touch ID and realized that the Touch ID was providing no security.

I believe this is because the methods that are supposed to run after Touch ID were outside of the LA Context block. I put them outside because I need to return a string value on a successful authorization (an internal employee number retrieved through XML). If I put the methods with the returned NSStrings outside of the LA Context block, the methods run in the wrong order.

How can I make the following 4 methods run in sequential order?
    1)requireLogin (Touch ID code here)
    2)requestSession
    3)readSession
    4)checkSession

If the Touch ID fails, methods 2-4 should not run.

I’ve looked at blocks. I’ve looked at GCD. I can’t find any examples on how to deal with this. If someone could point me in the right direction. I would really appreciate it. If I need to include more of the code, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

```
- (NSString *)retrieveESN {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/session.txt"];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]==YES) {
        _finished = false;
        NSLog(@"File exists");
        [self readSession];
        NSLog(@"%@", _sessionDetail);
        NSLog(@"Pre Check Session");
        NSString *result = [self checkSession:_sessionDetail];
        NSLog(@"Post Check Session");
        NSLog(@"%@", result);
        if ([result isEqualToString:@"Error"]) {
            NSLog(@"Error received - going into newFile");
            NSString *userESN = [self newFile];
            NSLog(@"Error'd returning with result");
            NSLog(@"UserESN: %@", userESN);
            return userESN;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"No Error Received");
            NSLog(@"Returning result: %@", result);
            return result;
        }
    } else {
        _finished = false;
        NSLog(@"No file exists, call newFile");
        NSString *userESN = [self newFile];
        NSLog(@"UserESN: %@", userESN);
        return userESN;
    }
}

- (NSString *)newFile {
    NSLog(@"File does not exist.");
    [self requireLogin];
    NSLog(@"Out of requireLogin");

    [self requestSession];
    NSLog(@"Out of requestSession");

   [self readSession];
   NSLog(@"Out of readSession");

    NSString *userESN = [self checkSession:_sessionDetail];
    NSLog(@"Into checkSession again newfile");
    return userESN;
}

- (void)requireLogin {
    LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"Into requireLogin");

    if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {
    // Authenticate User
        [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                localizedReason:@"You must log in to the app."
                          reply:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                              if (success) {
                                  _finished = true;
                                  NSLog(@"success");
                              } else {
                                  switch (error.code) {
                                      case LAErrorAuthenticationFailed:
                                            NSLog(@"Authentication Failed");
                                            break;
                                      case LAErrorUserCancel:
                                            NSLog(@"User pressed Cancel button");
                                            break;
                                      case LAErrorUserFallback:
                                            //Return to go to Enter Password not available screen.
                                            NSLog(@"User pressed Enter Password");
                                            break;

                                      default:
                                          NSLog(@"Touch ID is not configured");
                                          break;
                              }
                              NSLog(@"Authentication Fails");
                          }
                      }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Phone doesn't support Touch ID.");
    }
}

- (void)requestSession {
    NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSString *url = @“https://companyurl.com/session_page”;
    NSLog(@"Got to requestSession");

    NSMutableString *postText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%@", idfv);

    [postText appendString:idfv];

    NSString *postBody = [NSString stringWithString:postText];

    XMLPostSecurity *postAction = [[XMLPostSecurity alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Got to PostAction");
    _sessionDetail = [postAction sendPostRequestToUrl:url withBody:postBody];
    NSLog(@"Session Detail: %@", _sessionDetail);

    FileSaving *saver = [[FileSaving alloc] init];

    [saver saveSession:self.sessionDetail];
    NSLog(@"Saved file.");
}

-(NSString *)readSession {
    NSLog(@"In to readSession.");
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/session.txt"];
    while ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]==NO);

    NSFileManager *fileManagerTwo;
    NSData *dataBuffer;
    fileManagerTwo = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/session.txt"];
    NSLog(@"Got Path");

    dataBuffer = [fileManagerTwo contentsAtPath:filePath];
    NSLog(@"databuffer created");
    _sessionDetail = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataBuffer encoding:(NSASCIIStringEncoding)];

    NSLog(@"File read: %@", _sessionDetail);

    return _sessionDetail;
}

-(NSString *)checkSession:(NSString *)sessionFound {
    NSLog(@"Into checkSession");
    NSDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"ollie/", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                      @"\\", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                      @"cookieName", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                      sessionFound, NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                      nil];
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
    NSArray *cookieArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cookie];
    NSDictionary *headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookieArray];

    NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@“https://companyurl.com/xmlfile.php”];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);

    NSURL *urlNew = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlNew];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

    self.parseData = NULL;

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"dataTaskWithRequest error: %@", error);
                                                    return;
                                                }

                                                if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                                    NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

                                                    if (statusCode != 200) {
                                                        NSLog(@"dataTaskWithRequest HTTP status code: %ld", (long)statusCode);

                                                        if (statusCode == 401) {
                                                            // Insert process for thumbprint and session cookie pull
                                                            NSLog(@"401 Error received");

                                                            NSFileManager *fileManagerThree = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                                                            NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                                                            NSString *sessionPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"session.txt"];
                                                            NSError *error;
                                                            BOOL success = [fileManagerThree removeItemAtPath:sessionPath error:&error];
                                                            if (success) {
                                                                NSLog(@"File deleted - check session.");
                                                            } else {
                                                                NSLog(@"File could not be deleted.");
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            NSLog(@"I got something other than 200 or 401");
                                                            return;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                self.parseData = data;
                                            }];
    [task resume];

    while ( self.parseData == NULL );

    ParseTypeXML *myParser = [[ParseTypeXML alloc] initWithData:self.parseData];
    if ([myParser.esn count] == 0) {
        return @"Error";
    } else {
        return myParser.esn[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: The authentication completes asynchronously, so you can't return a value from `retrieveESN`; you need to pass a completion handler block to this function and then invoke this block with the retrieved data in the completion handler for the asynchronous function

Comment: Could you edit your code without logs, it is really hard to read now?

Comment: Put methods 2-4 in your completion block where you have the code `NSLog(@"success");`

Comment: I will refrain from including logs next time. Thank you, wottle, that worked!

Comment: I have come to realize that you were right, @Paulw11. Unfortunately, I can't quite grasp how to do this. Can you point me to a reference that will explain how to invoke the block with the retrieved data? I have looked at the block questions here on Stack Overflow and haven't found one that explains this to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.